# jqGrid beforeProcessing stop loading and ReloadGrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

This is my example: [enter link description here](http://firepic.org/images/2015-12/03/m63eo9d1juq3.gif)

How to reload automatically?

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) { 
    if (data.rows === '') {
        $('#jqGridPreparate').jqGrid('clearGridData');
        return false;
    }
    if (data.inputCol) {
        $("td.ui-search-input input#id_prep").val('');
        $("td.ui-search-input input#id_opisanie").val(data.inputCol);
        var rplc = $.parseJSON($("#jqGridPreparate")[0].p.postData.filters);
        for (var i=0; i < rplc.rules.length; i++) {
            if (rplc.rules[i].field === 'prep') {
                rplc.rules[i].field = 'opisanie';
            }
        }
        $.extend($("#jqGridPreparate")[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(rplc)});
        $("#jqGridPreparate")[0].triggerToolbar(); // not WORK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I full understand what you want to implement. I can guess that you want to apply the filter if some additional information will returned by from the server.

It seems that you implemented some custom agreement between jqGrid and the server about returned data. `rows` part of the server response should be array of items. In your case the server could set empty string as the value of `rows` instead. You try to use `inputCol` property of the server response to force filtering of **previously loaded data**. You makes some custom modifications of *existing* filter, you fill some fields of the filter toolbar and finally you try to use `triggerToolbar`. The code is very unclear and it contains a lot of assumptions which you don't described directly. It's not clear for me whether you want to start *local* filtering or jqGrid should send new request to the server with modified filter.

In any way, if you want to start some kind of reloading/filtering inside of other callback function, you shuld take in consideration some basic rules. First of all the method `triggerToolbar` or triggering `reloadGrid` works **synchronously**. It means that jqGrid first makes `triggerToolbar`, which makes `reloadGrid`, till the end and then will be executed the next line of code after `$("#jqGridPreparate")[0].triggerToolbar();`. Because of that it's strictly recommended to place all calls of `triggerToolbar` or `reloadGrid` inside of `setTimeout` body. It allows to process the current callback til the end and only then to make reloading. If the response from the server contains your custom information instead of typical jqGrid data then you should return `false` from `beforeProcessing` to stop the standard processing.

If you can construct `postData.filters` then you don't need to use `triggerToolbar` to apply the filter. Instead of that you need just set `search: true` parameter of jqGrid additionally and just trigger `reloadGrid`.

The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    if (data.rows === "") {
        $self.jqGrid("clearGridData");
        return false; // don't process the data by jqGrid
    }
    if (data.inputCol) {
        var i, rplc = $.parseJSON(p.postData.filters);
        for (i = 0; i < rplc.rules.length; i++) {
            if (rplc.rules[i].field === "prep") {
                rplc.rules[i].field = "opisanie";
            }
        }
        p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(rplc);
        setTimeout(function () {
            // apply the filter
            p.search = true;
            $self.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
        }, 50);
        return false; // don't process the data by jqGrid
    }
}
```